# Google Maps getting kml data and display them

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need your help. I want to make a map from the Netherlands, where you can click and the province/state name and google maps is than showing the province with the borders. I have found a good example for that:
http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_CountryBrowser.html

My problem is that I don't now where they get the data from. From Google or there own database? Also I didn't understand how the display the data. With the library geoxml3_kmlStr.js? It's in the code: `<script type="text/javascript" src="geoxml3_kmlStr.js"></script>`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_CountryBrowser.html
comes from a [FusionTable](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=420419).

from [that example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_CountryBrowser.html) (the "old" "numeric" id):

```
// Fusion Table data ID
var FT_TableID = 420419;
```

If you go to [that fusion table](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=420419), you will see this (in "File > About this table") (both the old "numeric id" and the current "encrypted id"):

```
Id  19lLpgsKdJRHL2O4fNmJ406ri9JtpIIk8a-AchA
Numeric ID 420419
```

The data in the FusionTable is being returned in the queries (using GViz, so is limited in the number of rows that can be queried) as KML snippets. The example uses the [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) third party KML parser to parse that and display it on the map.

For the [Netherlands](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_CountryBrowser.html?country=Netherlands).

Comment: Thanks for your help! Du I need a extra library to get the data from the FusionTable or is that a simple ajax request? is it also possible to display the kml snippets via a kml layer from google maps?

Comment: It is using GViz (the google [visualization library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/visualization)) to query the FusionTable.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added now `http://www.google.com/jsapi` and `geoxml3_kmlStr.js` to the script files. And have written this function:
http://pastebin.com/cQM7NVMx . Name is here the `name` of the province and is given from the other code, also the `CountryName`. I have also a map called `map` My problem is, that when I add this function to the site, the source of the side will only be `<script src="http://www.google.com/uds/?file=visualization&v=1&packages=corechart%2Cgeomap%2Ctable" type="text/javascript"></script>` What do I wrong?

Comment: That is a new question (or at least it could be if you 1. verify that it isn't a duplicate of an already existing question and 2. created a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrated your issue in that question)